# Scrolling Navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll

I am all new to JQuery and this question must've been asked million times before. My website will be 4 page into one page. I want to keep my navigation menu like it is here on this website http://www.oncarbure.com/en.html
on the bottom at the first page and on top on rest of the pages. Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks alot.

Comment: If it's been asked million times before, you should've found an answer already if you did a search. :)

Comment: I don't actually see any navigation apart from the Info/fr...

Comment: Thats the problem, I did not.

Comment: Yeah that "fetured work" and "Info/fr" thing, instead of that I want to keep a navigation menu.

Comment: so you just want to have it positioned at the bottom of the page?

Comment: In the beginning yes, but later at top. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS only

If you just want your menu to be positioned at the bottom of the page, than fixed positioning will do the trick for you:

```
.menu
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #333;
}
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4F3M/) shows a simplified example.

When you'd want to position it at the top afterwards, just set `top: 0;` and it will be moved to the top and won't be moved with scrolling.

#### Example page notes

Example page you referred to uses advanced techniques that you're likely not after (at least not at first) as I understand your comments.

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for something like this http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/313_waypoints/demo/index.html

Comment: Why don't you check that page how it's done? This combines CSS and javascript animations. And as said it's much more complex than simple positioning.